# OpenCV bad performance (object detection)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I am developing a small application where clients can control a robot via their browser for my studies. Actually the clients don't see the robots and therefore I provide a webcam live stream via MJPEG.

I am using OpenCV 2.4.9 and Visual C++.

On the frames of the webcam stream I perform several operations like:

- overlaying the frame with some transparent images
- detecting the robots
- ...

My performance problems occur in the detection methods of the robots. Sometimes the detection needs about 20 - 30 ms and sometimes up to (!) 900ms. I have no idea why there are so big performance differences.

### Some details

**Used shapes:**

For the detection I use two difference shapes as you can see here:
[image: Robot shapes]

One robot has a black circle with a white triangle in it and the other one has a rectangle with a triangle in it - both with a black border and white filling.

**The code:**

I have figured out that these lines of code a the main source of the performance loss:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;

findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), approx, cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.1, true);

    // Skip small or non-convex objects
    if (std::fabs(cv::contourArea(contours[i])) < 100 || !cv::isContourConvex(approx))
        continue;

    if (approx.size() == 3)
    {
        triangles.push_back(approx);
        trianglePositions.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

This code is used to detect the positions of the rectangles and triangles on a frame.

Sometimes the performance of this method call needs up to 130 ms:

```
Mat srcdetect2; //the original webcam frame
Mat src_graydetect2;
cvtColor(srcdetect2, src_graydetect2, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

The third line is this one (also up to 100 ms):

```
blur(src_graydetect2, src_graydetect2, Size(3, 3));
```

The last line I figured out was this:

```
int threshdetect2 = 100;
int max_threshdetect2 = 255;
Canny(src_graydetect2, canny_output, threshdetect2, threshdetect2 * 2, 3);
```

I am sitting now several hours in front of this piece of code and I have no idea why I am losing the performance here.

This code is called by several threads with different webcam frames to improve the throughput. I use the webcam with 15 FPS.

Does anybody of you see the problem? Any help is welcome!

Thank you very much

Comment: If you anticipate  that `trianglePositions.push_back(i);` is only going to be executed once per frame, then you can `break` after it to stop the loop earlier.

Comment: I tried this but the result was that the robots were not always detected since OpenCV detected several triangles :/